# Пользовательское выравнивание в системе уравнений в Word

Tags: ms-word, formula, align

В документе Word используются математические системы уравнений, собранные в фигурные скобки.

Каждая формула в системе выровнена по центру.

[image: формулы тестовые]

Вопрос: как можно выровнять формулы по-другому (по левому краю, по знаку равно)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая странная магия, узнал случайно

становитесь в каждую строчку перед знаком равно и добавляете амперсанд. Ворд его не показывает, но выравнивает по этим амперсандам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же можно расставить перед х и y и выравнять по переменным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Word их показывает, если включить отображение спец символов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно поставить символ амперсанда перед началом каждого из выражений и тоже работает